# Can you mount a floor-standing bookcase on the wall and which fittings would you use?

Tags: walls, cabinets

Is it possible to mount what should be a floor-standing storage unit on the wall?  I am redoing my kitchen and have found a large oak bookcase with doors that I wanted to mount on the wall but I wasn't sure if it would be too heavy.  We have solid walls.  And what fixings would you recommend?

Dimensions: 196cm x 175cm x 39cm

[image]

Comment: can you provide dimensions of the unit? when you say mount to the wall do you mean off of the ground or just secured to the wall?

Comment: Remember the fixings have to support the unit PLUS the contents... How much will the contents weigh...

Comment: The unit is 196cm by 175cm by 39cm.  I have no idea of the weight.  It would be used to store crockery and food, which would obviously add quite a bit of weight.http://www.antik-spomysl.cz/produkt/kancelarska-skrin-3/

Comment: Please post photos or a description of the back panel construction. If it's similar to a kitchen cabinet, the same approach can probably be used. If not, you'll need  a cleat underneath.

Comment: I'm also curious what the toe-kick frame does at the back. You may be able to fasten that to the wall as a support cleat (if you don't intend to remove it).

Comment: It also depends on the strength of the wall. Interior,  non-load-bearing walls might not be strong enough, even if the bookcase were attached to studs. The wall is designed to bear vertical loads. Is it worth the risk that the wall would bend eventually from the torque of the extended bookcase?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want it on the floor?

Comment: that cabinet may not withstand being mounted on the wall ... the front may start sagging ... first child that climbs into the cabinet may separate the bottom from the rest of the cabinet

Answer (score 3):

You don't say how high off the floor you'd like this cabinet mounted. To mount the cabinet properly on the wall, you'll have two forces you must counteract properly. If you fail to counteract either of the forces, you'll hear a crash sound.

From this point on, when I say cabinet, I mean the cabinet and the heaviest contents it would ever have.

Force 1: The weight of the cabinet. This is a shear force. It wants to slide the cabinet down the wall.

Force 2: the tension (pulling force) caused by the weight of the front of the cabinet. This is strongest at the top of the cabinet, and would want to pull screws out of the wall. This is probably a much smaller force.

To counteract the shear force #1, consider adding back legs to the cabinet. This could be as simple as cutting a piece of plywood as wide as the cabinet and as high as the gap between the floor and the cabinet's bottom. The weight of the cabinet will press down on the plywood, which will press on the floor. We'll assume the floor can carry the weight of the cabinet (and the plywood!).

Alternately, you may be able to only screw a shorter strip of wood to your wall (a rail). This strip might be 5 cm tall plywood, slightly narrower than the width of your cabinet. You'd use strong screws fastened into wood behind your wall covering. This is how Elfa closet systems hang from closet walls- using a rail or cleat.

To counteract the tension force #2, you could put front legs on the cabinet, but that defeats the hanging look. Instead, you can use screws that resist pulling out and screw them through the back of the cabinet into wood behind your wall covering. Keep these points in mind:

1. The back of the cabinet must also be securely fastened to the cabinet sides and top. If not, the cabinet will tear off the wall, leaving the back of the cabinet nicely attached to the wall. Not a good result.
2. The screw heads must be large enough not to tear through the cabinet back material. If the cabinet back material is paperboard, you will need a rail on the inside of the cabinet back to spread the force across the entire cabinet back. Otherwise, the cabinet back will tear around the screw. You'll see screws poking out of your wall with little bits of cabinet back stuck to them. Also not a good result.